# Need to add perfmon in HTML file of jmeter

Tags: html, jmeter, report, perfmon

I am trying to configure perfmon in html, but it is showing error. I have tried multiple steps but still shows error.

What I have tried.

- Steps I followed (Checked in version 5.4 and 5.5)
- First, I have downloaded plugins for perfmon from JMeter plugin manager.
- Downloaded sever agent and started startAgent.bat. (Successfully started)
- Executed test and received graphs in JMeter Perfmon graph
  [image]
- Same I can open it in aggregate reports Aggregate report
  [image]
- I have then added below points in user.properties file (**from here issue started**)

### Custom graph definition

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.title=PerfmonMetrics
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.property.set_Y_Axis=Usage in %
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.property.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.property.setSampleVariableName=ts-hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_Perfmon.property.setContentMessage=Message for graph point label
```

Added ts-hit in perfmon name
[image]

Error that I am facing

[image]

Error generating the report:

> org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while
> processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with
> message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message
> :No column <"ts-hit"> found in sample metadata
> <timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect>,
> check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare this `ts-hit` as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables). For example by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=ts-hit
```

The [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) expects the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) to have `ts-hit` column so you need to provide the values to that column for each Sampler. The options are in:

1. Transfer the values from the `Abc3.csv` file manually using Excel or equivalent
2. Obtain the value of the metric you need dynamically via i.e. TCP Sampler by sending the appropriate request, for example `metrics-single:cpu`. Then you can store the value from the Server Agent using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) into `ts-hit` JMeter Variable and it will be automatically picked up and plotted during HTML Reporting Dashboard generation.