# How to incorporate perfmon (plugin) stats into the standard JMeter report

Tags: jmeter, reporting, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I'm using the perfmon plugin within JMeter to collect stats like CPU usage and would like to display this in a custom (over time) graph in the standard JMeter HTML report.

So far I have a custom graph which allows me to display any variable I like from the test script. However the problem seems to be that I can't pass samples from the perfmon collector to a variable in order to get them on the graph.

I suspect the problem may be that the custom graphs are geared around using a SAMPLER, whereas the perfmon plugin is a LISTENER.

I realise the perfmon listener can also output to a CSV file but isn't there a way to extract values from the perfmon listener which would facilitate usage on a custom graph?

Is there another way to sample the CPU usage which makes the information available to custom graphs in the HTML report?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your colleague has asked the [identical question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730051/need-to-add-perfmon-in-html-file-of-jmeter)

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=cpu
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=CPU Usage
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=CPU Usage %
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=cpu
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=CPU Usage :
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan and put the following code there:

   ```
   def s = new Socket("your-system-under-test-ip-or-hostname", 4444);
   s.setSoTimeout(3000);
   s << "metrics-single:cpu\n";
   s.withStreams { inStream, outStream ->
     def reader = inStream.newReader()
     def response = reader.readLine()
     vars.put('cpu', response)
   }
   s.close()
   ```

This way when a Sample occurs the JSR223 Listener will query the Server Agent for CPU usage and store the value into `cpu` variable. The variable values for each Sampler will be added to the .jtl results file and you will be able to plot them over your test execution time span.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)